# Not finding link using display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a unique problem with my header when I style my links using the table-cell attribute.

The link is only clickable at its base and cannot be clicked in the center, but can at the top. This problem couldn't be recreated in an online example but effects all browsers.

After researching similar problems, I tried changing line-height but that had no effect. Other possible solutions suggested not using table-cell but that is how I have already aligned the header and it would be cumbersome to change all of the aligning.

Another thing I noticed is that when inspect element is opened, it shows the link as three separate cells all in one vertical column.

Pictures to show the problem:
[image: Top of the Link]
[image: Middle of Link]
[image: Bottom of Link]

```css
header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
header nav {
  width: 60%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav div {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
header nav hr {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
header p:hover {
  color: #DE4738;
}
header nav div:hover {
  color: #DE4738;
}
header img {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: auto;
}
header nav div p {
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #DE4738;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </a>
    <nav>
      <div>
        <a href="asdf.html">
          <p><i>asdf</i>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <a href="adsf.html">
          <p><i>asdf</i>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <a href="Asdf.html">
          <p><i>asdf</i>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <a href="asdf.html">
          <p><i>asdf</i>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't see the issue copying your markup. Which browser? We probably need more markup.

Comment: @Rob The problem isn't replicated when put into JSFiddle, the problem arises in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Hopefully the pictures can provide context.

Comment: Well, I don't see it in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Might be a caching issue? if it works in JSFiddle with exactly the same code, it looks like the browsers arent noticing that your CSS/HTML is changing.  Have you cleared the caches?

Comment: @JoeSakett did you find the solution to this? it might be worth adding it and accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run your content I could replicate your formatting issues if I used a malformed style tag.

No changes to your CSS were made, but I changed the HTML to the following:

I added the HTML5 doctype, html, head and style tags to get it working in a file locally.  It then rendered correctly in both Firefox and IE.  I dont have Chrome to test it on here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*copy paste your CSS in here */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>
        <nav>
            <div>
                <a href="asdf.html">
                    <p><i>asdf</i></p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <a href="adsf.html">
                    <p><i>asdf</i></p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <a href="Asdf.html">
                    <p><i>asdf</i></p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <a href="asdf.html">
                    <p><i>asdf</i></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That isn't the problem, I failed to include the opening tags due to saving space on the question. All of the tags are valid and the CSS is linked correctly.